# Convert XML column to SQL column

Tags: sql-server

I have a column field called `datafields` in XML format.

```
select top 1 datafields 
from u3_list.dbo.list with (nolock)
where accountID = '833543A3-B29F-4029-8F77-08D7B6D24123'
```

This code returns:

```
<ListDataFields>
  <fields>
    <field id="89f188f8-762f-4d6e-b27b-08d7b6d24ffb" name="U3L_ID" display-name="ID">The sequential ID for each contact</field>
    <field id="b3840996-930a-43f6-adf0-08d7b6d24ffb" name="U3L_ReferenceID" display-name="Reference ID">Globally Unique GUID for each contact</field>
    <field id="71f60810-15dc-4c7f-8d88-08d7b6d24ffb" name="U3L_PersonID" display-name="Person ID">Share to Social ID</field>
    <field id="0c92917d-e234-45f6-9b0a-08d7b6d24ffb" name="U3L_Source" display-name="Source">Where each contact originated</field>
    <field id="1938b8cf-a9a3-440a-b7c1-08d7b6d24ffb" name="U3L_CreateDate" display-name="Create Date">Create date/time for each contact</field>
    <field id="363a3efa-f7a9-4b7c-9a8f-08d7b6d24ffb" name="U3L_LastModified" display-name="Last Modified">Last modified date/time for each contact</field>
    <field id="68bd4d1d-c2aa-422c-984a-08d7b6d24ffb" name="U3L_Version" display-name="Version">Incremented each time a contact is updated</field>
  </fields>
</ListDataFields>
```

I would like to return this as following format

```
id                                    DisplayName
--------------------------------------------------------
89f188f8-762f-4d6e-b27b-08d7b6d24ffb  ID
b3840996-930a-43f6-adf0-08d7b6d24ffb  Reference ID
71f60810-15dc-4c7f-8d88-08d7b6d24ffb  Person ID
```

I tried the following but the syntax is not correct

```
select 
    x.r.value('(@id)[1]','varchar(500)') as id,
    x.r.value('(@display-name)[1],''varchar(500)') as displayName
from 
    u3_list.dbo.list.Datafields.nodes('/ListDataFields/fields/field)' as x(r) with (nolock)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select x.r.value('(@id)[1]','varchar(100)') as id,
        x.r.value('(@display-name)[1]','varchar(100)') as displayName
from u3_list.dbo.list with (nolock)
    cross apply datafields.nodes('/ListDataFields/fields/field') as x(r)
where accountID = '833543A3-B29F-4029-8F77-08D7B6D24123'
```